# How to navigate to error page from Nuxt store

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuex

```js
export const state = () => ({
  data: {}
})

export const getters = {
  data: state => state.data
}

export const actions = {
  getData ({ commit }) {
    this.$axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todosx/1')
      .then((response) => {
        commit('SET_DATA', response.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          // Navigate to error page
      })
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_DATA (state, data) {
    state.data = data
  }
}
```

After catching error in the catch for the axios would like to navigate to the error page from the **Nuxt store**. What will be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `this.$router.push('/404')` should do the trick since it either exist or it will use the `error` layout since it cannot reach the page.

Comment: Btw, you could maybe make it more smooth in the template and display a "no info here" rather than moving the user to a 404, don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes would like to show custom error template here. So for that is it possible to send something like **$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'err message' })** just like in the pages. I tried to do the same in store and failed to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

In your `catch` you can redirect the user to the error page by

```
return this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Your error message' })
```

and in your `error.vue` page you can access it with error prop like:

```
<h1>{{ error.statusCode }}</h1>
<h2>{{ error.message }} </h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does work in the page but inside vuex store it giving me another error **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')**. While printing **this.$nuxt** it is showing **undefined**. Is there any way I can access **this.$nuxt** in vuex store?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of template should work fine on top of `$nuxt.error`

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['error'],
}
</script>
```

As shown in the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/layouts#error-page